# Generalized Likelihood Ratio Tests and Composite Hypotheses

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I'm not quite sure that I understand how the generalized likelihood ratio test works for composite hypotheses; observe the example below:

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from an exponential distribution, $X_i\sim EXP(\theta) \implies E(X_i)=\theta$.  Derive the generalized likelihood ratio test of $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ vs. $H_a: \theta>\theta_0$.

I've been able to to a good portion of the work; we know that, in this case, $\bar{X}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$.  But here's where I'm confused.  Suppose instead we had that $H_0: \theta=\theta_0$ vs. $H_a:\theta\ne\theta_0$.  **If** this were true instead, we would have that the likelihood ratio is given by:
 $$\lambda(\vec{X})=\frac{\bar{x}^n e^{-n\bar{x}/\theta_0+n}}{\theta_0^n}$$
And then we would reject the null hypothesis if this value was less than some constant $c$.  However, considering that a **composite hypothesis is given instead**, I believe that the decision rule needs to change somehow; the problem is that I don't understand how.  The textbook lists the following as the final answer to the original question:

> Reject $H_0$ if $2n\bar{x}/\theta_0 \ge \chi^2_{1-\alpha}(2n))$

where $\chi^2_{1-\alpha}(2n)$ represents the percentile function of the chi square distribution with $2n$ degrees of freedom.  Can somebody show how to work to this solution; I don't know how they get there because this is a composite hypothesis and I don't understand what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test#Composite_hypotheses,
$$
{\displaystyle \Lambda (X)={\frac {\sup\{\,{\mathcal {L}}(\theta \mid X):\theta \in \Theta _{0}\,\}}{\sup\{\,{\mathcal {L}}(\theta \mid X):\theta \in \Theta \,\}}}} = \begin{cases}
 \frac{e^{-n\overline{x}/\theta_0}/\theta_0^n}{e^{-n \overline{x}/\overline{x}}/  (\overline{x})^n} = \frac{\bar{x}^n e^{-n\bar{x}/\theta_0+n}}{\theta_0^n} &  \overline{X} > \theta_0\\[10pt]
\frac{e^{-n\overline{x}/\theta_0}/\theta_0^n}{e^{-n \overline{x}/\theta_0}/  \theta_0^n} =1 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

We reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_a$ if this is sufficiently small. Only the first case is interesting.

> "And then we would reject the null hypothesis if this value was less than some constant c"

After doing this, you will see that we reject null hypothesis for  $\overline{X}$ sufficiently large, or equivalently, for $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ sufficiently large.

The result follows after observing that, under the null hypothesis, $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \Gamma(n,\theta_0)$ and therefore $ \frac{2}{\theta_0} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim \chi^2(2n)$ using properties of Gamma distribution.

Comment: My problem wasn't understanding the why the chi square distribution shows up, it was the formation of the decision rule as dependent on the fact that this is a GLR test with a composite hypothesis; reread what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

We are assessing the following hypothesis:
\begin{align*}
    H_0: \theta \le \theta_0 && H_1: \theta = \theta_1 > \theta_0
\end{align*}
In this case, the domains of the null and alternative parameters are:
\begin{align*}
    \Theta_0 = (-\infty, \theta_0] && \Theta_1 = (\theta_0, \infty)
\end{align*}
Let us first take the case where $\theta_0 > \hat{\theta}_{MLE}$. Taking a generic likelihood function, the domain, $\Theta_0$, over which we are performing the restricted MLE includes $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}$.

[An image of the generic likelihood function, its MLE over the whole domain and the selection of theta naught greater than theta MLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqOOh.png)

The blue dotted line is $\theta_0$ and the black dotted line is $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}$. This example graph makes it clear that the domain $\Theta_0$ (shaded in green) includes the MLE when $\theta_0>\hat{\theta}_{MLE}$. Therefore, the restricted MLE $\theta_0=\hat{\theta}_{MLE}$ when $\theta_0 > \hat{\theta}_{MLE}$.

Next, we consider the case when $\theta_0 \le \hat{\theta}_{MLE}$. In this case, we can redraw the graph to again help us visualize:

[An image where we have theta naught less than theta MLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en9Pb.png)

Now we can see that the restricted maximum likelihood as given by the shaded green region must be $\theta_0$ given that it is the largest value of the likelihood. There is the special case that $\theta_0= \hat{\theta}_{MLE}$, in which case this rule will still hold.

Therefore, our likelihood ratio test statistic is:
\begin{align*}
    \lambda(\mathbf{x})=\frac{L(\hat{\theta}_0)}{L(\hat{\theta}_{MLE})}=\begin{cases}
        \frac{L(\hat{\theta}_{MLE})}{L(\hat{\theta}_{MLE})}=1, &\hat{\theta}_{MLE} \le \theta_0\\[10pt]
        \frac{L(\hat{\theta}_0)}{L(\hat{\theta}_{MLE})}, &\hat{\theta}_{MLE} > \theta_0
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

This video also gives an excellent explanation of the composite hypothesis issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RvLy554NnI.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2081044)

Comment: Thanks, I've answered the question and left the link.